# Converting FASTQ to FASTA with SED/AWK

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

I have a data in that always comes in block of four
in the following format (called FASTQ):

```
@SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
+SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+!
@SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
+SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
7);;).;);;/;*.2>/@@7;@77<..;)58)5/>/
```

Is there a simple sed/awk/bash way to convert them into 
this format (called FASTA):

```
>SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

In principle, we want to extract the first two lines in each block-of-4
and replace `@` with `>`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an old question, and there have been many different solutions offered.  Since the accepted answer uses sed but has a glaring problem (which is that it will replace @ with > when the @ sign appears as the first letter of the quality line), I feel compelled to offer a simple sed-based solution that actually works:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p'
```

The only assumption made is that each read occupies exactly 4 lines in the FASTQ file, but that seems pretty safe, in my experience.

The fastq_to_fasta script in the fastx toolkit also works.  (It's worth mentioning that you need to specify the -Q33 option to accommodate the now common Phred+33 qual encodings.  Which is funny, since it's throwing away the quality data anyway!)

Comment: Thank you! Because of this nice line of code, I finally made decision to learn sed more thoroughly. Here is a good source: grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15 I still have one question though: what does "~" do there please? Thanks

Comment: To translate the sed expression verbatim:  "starting on line 1, and every 4th line thereafter, when you see a @ character at the beginning of a line, substitute it with a > character, and print the resulting line; then, starting at line 2, and every 4th line thereafter, just print the line".   The -n option turns off automatic printing, and the 'p' in the two sed expressions selectively prints lines that match the expression.  hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

sed ain't dead.  If we're golfing:

```
sed '/^@/!d;s//>/;N'
```

Or, emulating http://www.ringtail.tsl.ac.uk/david-studholme/scripts/fastq2fasta.pl posted by Pierre, which only prints the first word (the id) from the first line and does (some) error handling:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
# Read a total of four lines
$b error
N;$b error
N;$b error
N
# Parse the lines
/^@\(\([^ ]*\).*\)\(\n[ACGTN]*\)\n+\1\n.*$/{
  # Output id and sequence for FASTA format.
  s//>\2\3/
  b
}
:error
i\
Error parsing input:
q
```

There seem to be plenty of existing tools for converting these formats; you should probably use these instead of anything posted here (including the above).

Comment: sed is very much alive, but the sed solution offered here will likely sink your workflow.  You can't rely on the @ character to uniquely indicate header lines -- quality lines can also start with @.  Please see my fix below.

Answer (score 9):

As detailed in Cock, et al (2009) NAR, many of these solutions are incorrect since "the ‘@’ marker character (ASCII 64) may occur anywhere in the quality string. This means that any parser must not treat a line starting with ‘@’ as indicating the start of the next record, without additionally checking the length of the quality string thus far matches the length of the sequence."

See http://ukpmc.ac.uk/articlerender.cgi?accid=PMC2847217 for details.

Comment: Not true for any solution specifying that the @ character is at the begining of the line with '^@', which seems to represent the majority of the answers. Cheers

Comment: Actually, this is a true statement since a quality value of @ can in principle occur anywhere in the quality string including the first character, '^@' is not guaranteed to catch the name lines only.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for not having taken a few more seconds to think about the problem properly. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

just awk , no need other tools

```
# awk '/^@SR/{gsub(/^@/,">",$1);print;getline;print}' file
>SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 4):

See **fastq2fasta.pl** in http://www.ringtail.tsl.ac.uk/david-studholme/scripts/

Answer (score 3):

I'd write

```
awk '
    NR%4 == 1 {print ">" substr($0, 2)}
    NR%4 == 2 {print}
' fastq > fasta
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest I've got, and I stuck it in my .bashrc file:

```
alias fq2fa="awk '{print \">\" substr(\$0,2);getline;print;getline;getline}'"
```

It doesn't fail on the infrequent but not impossible quality lines that start with @... but does fail on wrapped FASTQ, if that's even legal (it exists though).

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in bioawk, it is an adapted version of awk which is tuned to process fasta files

```
bioawk -c fastx '{ print ">"$name ORS $seq }' file.fastq
```

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{P=1}{if(P==1||P==2){gsub(/^[@]/,">");print}; if(P==4)P=0; P++}' data

>SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
>SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

below

```
awk '{gsub(/^[@]/,">"); print}' data
```

where data is your data file.
I've received:

```
>SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGN
+SRR018006.2016 GA2:6:1:20:650 length=36
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+!
>SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
ACCCGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
+SRR018006.19405469 GA2:6:100:1793:611 length=36
7);;).;);;/;*.2>/@@7;@77<..;)58)5/>/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to the "skip every other line" part of the problem that I just learned from SO:

```
while read line
do
    # print two lines
    echo "$line"
    read line_to_print
    echo "$line_to_print"

    # and skip two lines
    read line_to_skip
    read line_to_skip
done
```

If all that needs to be done is change one `@` to `>`, then I reckon

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/@/>/'
    read line
    echo "$line"

    read line_to_skip
    read line_to_skip
done
```

will do the job.

Comment: there should be an input redirection for the input file. to replace characters in bash, ${line/@/>} should suffice. no need sed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0}{if(a==1){print;a=0}}/^@/{print;a=1}' myFastqFile | sed 's/^@/>/'
```

should work.

Comment: since you are using awk already, there is no need to waste an extra process calling sed. do the substitution inside awk.

Answer (score 1):

I think, with gnu grep this could be done with this:

```
grep -A 1 "^@" t.txt | grep -v "^--" | sed -e "s/^@/\>/"
```

Comment: if the file happens to be very big, there's no point chaining greps and sed together like that.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm way in the future, but for the benefit of googlers:

You may want to use [fastq_to_fasta from the fastx toolkit](http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/commandline.html#fastq_to_fasta_usage). It will keep the @ sign, though. It will also remove lines with Ns unless you tell it not to.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. For example, for common next generation sequencing data processing tasks, use `seqtk`.

```
seqtk seq -A in.fq > out.fa
```

To install these tools, use `conda`, specifically `miniconda`, for example:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqtk seqtk
conda activate seqtk
# ... use seqtk here ...
conda deactivate
```

**References:**

`seqtk`: https://github.com/lh3/seqtk
`conda`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html
`conda create`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html